# Converting a rawValue into a string in Swift

Tags: swift

Apple has made changes from Swift 3 to 4. When I run the following code:

```
let metadata = [ PDFDocumentAttribute.titleAttribute,
                 PDFDocumentAttribute.authorAttribute,
                 PDFDocumentAttribute.subjectAttribute,
                 PDFDocumentAttribute.creatorAttribute,
                 PDFDocumentAttribute.producerAttribute,
                 PDFDocumentAttribute.creationDateAttribute,
                 PDFDocumentAttribute.modificationDateAttribute,
                 PDFDocumentAttribute.keywordsAttribute ]

if var attributes = pdfDoc.documentAttributes {

    for (index, value) in metadata.enumerated() {
        if attributes[value] != nil {

            print("\(metadata[index])): \(String(describing: attributes[value]!))")
        }    else {
            print("\(metadata[index]): nil")
        }
    }
```

I now get: *PDFDocumentAttribute(_rawValue: Title)* instead of "Title", which I got before as the value of `metadata[index]`.

How do I get rid of the rawValue stuff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `PDFDocumentAttribute` type has a property called `rawValue` that contains the old string value. So you can say

```
print("\(metadata[index].rawValue): \(String(describing: attributes[value]!))")
```

---

As an aside, instead of force-unwrapping the attribute you can use an `if let`, as in

```
if let attr = attributes[value] {
    print("\(metadata[index].rawValue): \(attr)")
} else {
    print("\(metadata[index].rawValue): nil")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add this extension:

```
extension PDFDocumentAttribute: CustomStringConvertible {
  public var description: String {
    return self.rawValue
  }
}
```

Now you can just do:

```
// Forcing the downcast has little risk here 
// but you may want to use `as?` and test for the optional instead
let attributes = pdfDoc.documentAttributes as! [PDFDocumentAttribute:Any]
for meta in metadata {
  print("\(meta): \(attributes[meta] ?? "nil")")
}
```

Note that you can also do:

```
for attribute in attributes {
  print("\(attribute.key): \(attribute.value)")
}
```

Which will just print out the attributes that exist on the document.